# ReactJS Access/Refresh Token Rotation Multiple Request Problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api, interceptor

I have an authentication service where I return an access token with an 15 min. validity and refresh token with a 4 day validity. I store the access token in an session storage, and if it expires I send an request to get a new access and refresh token. This rotation works fine.

I am using native fetch API in ReactJS to achieve. I monkey patched the original fetch to intercept the requests and send a request for refreshing the token if the validity expires.

```
      if (!accessToken.expired) {
        requestHeaders.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken.value}`);
      }

      if (accessToken.expired) {
        const refreshToken = storageHandler.GetCookie('refresh_token');

      const data: RefreshAuthenticationRequestDto = {
          accessToken: accessToken.value,
          refreshToken,
        };
        await originalFetch(createRequestUrl(apiUrl.coreRefreshUrl), {
          method: RequestType.Post,
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            accept: 'application/json',
          },
        })
        // update the data with new values
```

This works just fine. However, I found out that if multiple requests is done at the same time when the access token validity expires I get error from the API that tells me refresh token is invalid. This happens because, let's say that there is a page that I need to fill with 3 requests, each of these requests goes to authentication server to get a new access token, and when the first one gets, its updates the refresh token therefore other two is automatically denied and I recieve an error.

How can I make sure that an when there is a need for refreshing the tokens the other requests wait until the token is refresh? Is it even possible to achieve this?